# ( i.e stylesheets) for different languages?

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer-9

```
<?php if($_COOKIE['lang'] != 'en') echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/'.$_COOKIE['lang'].'.css"/>'; ?>
```

With this above script you get the stylesheet for the language that is selected.
Like if you select France you get the stylesheet `fr.css`

But now I want the same for `IE` so I thought something like this.

```
<?php if($_COOKIE['lang'] != 'en') echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/'.$_COOKIE['lang'].'ie.css"/>'; ?>
```

So now when you click on `France` it also opens `frie.css`
But what do I write in here to make it only for `IE`

```
<!--[if IE]><style>@import url('/css/ie.css');</style><![endif]-->
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 
 if($_COOKIE['lang'] != 'en'){ 
    printf('<!--[if IE]><style>@import url(\'/css/%sie.css\');</style><![endif]-->', $_COOKIE['lang']); 
 }
?>
```

This is what you need to write. You can also check in PHP headers if browser is Internet Explorer.

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` or [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function to check it in PHP.

Comment: What does the %s mean?

Comment: It means string which will be replaced by `$_COOKIE['lang']` in this case. Check printf() function manual

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

You can refer to below line :

https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/